# Make a Circle Fade?

Tags: sketch-3, sketchapp

I have the following image. I am using Sketch.

[image]

How can I make the white circle fade into the Green background?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a fade effect by adding gradient to your circle from white (circle color) to transparent.

That's how it will look :

[image]